# Structs not being initialized

Tags: c#, types, struct, static, clr

Today, I figured out it might be interesting to have some sort of enumeration in C# similar to the class enums in Java (which has been done numerous times) but as immutable structs. I came up with something like this:

```
public struct TestStruct {

    public static readonly TestStruct Value1 = 1;
    public static readonly TestStruct Value2 = 2;
    public static readonly TestStruct Value3 = 3;

    private int _value;

    private TestStruct(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(TestStruct instance) {
        return instance._value;
    }

}
```

<strike>The code compiles fine</strike>, however when I try to access `TestStruct.Value2`, a `NullReferenceException` occurs.

This was just a test, but now I'm wondering.. what happens to the *static readonly* `TestStructs`? Why can I assign an integer to them, although they are not being initialized?

**Update**

This one compiles.

```
public struct LogLevel
{
    // log levels
    public static readonly LogLevel Information = 0x0000;
    public static readonly LogLevel Warning = 0x0001;
    public static readonly LogLevel Error = 0x0002;
    public static readonly LogLevel Verbose = 0x0004;
    public static readonly LogLevel Debug = 0x0008;
    public static readonly LogLevel Trace = 0x0016;
    public static readonly LogLevel Critical = 0x0032;
    public static readonly LogLevel Fatal = 0x0064;


    private static readonly Dictionary<int, LogLevel> Levels
        = new Dictionary<int, LogLevel>();

    private readonly int _value;

    private LogLevel(int value)
    {
        if (Levels.ContainsKey(value))
            throw new ArgumentException("Level already defined.");

        _value = value;
        Levels.Add(value, this);
    }

    public static implicit operator LogLevel(int value)
    {
        LogLevel level;
        if (!Levels.TryGetValue(value, out level))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        return level;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(LogLevel level)
    {
        return level._value;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

```
    // extension method for log levels
    public static void Debug(this ILogger logger, string message)
    {
        logger.Write(message, LogLevel.Debug);
    }

    // method on ILogger, implementation is Log4NetLogger (wrapper)
    void Write(string message, LogLevel severity);

    // call (simple)
    Logger.Debug("Test");
```

Comment: This would be an interesting question if it compiled - but it doesn't. Please give a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The code compiles fine? Are you sure? We can't. My guess is you have a `class` instead of `struct`, that also doesn't compile..

Comment: Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CL9pLF. If you had a `implicit operator TestStruct(int instance)` it would compile. But still no `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, you're right. Forgot to copy that. Made a new example that compiles.

Comment: So it compiles... but you haven't given anything *using* it... (Again: think *short* but *complete* example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You're using the implicit conversion from `int` when you're initializing the fields... that expects the value to already *be* there. You should be using the constructor instead. So this:

   ```
   public static readonly LogLevel Information = 0x0000;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   public static readonly LogLevel Information = new LogLevel(0x0000);
   ```
2. You're trying to access the dictionary before the `Levels` variable has been initialized. You need to move this statement:

   ```
   private static readonly Dictionary<int, LogLevel> Levels
       = new Dictionary<int, LogLevel>();
   ```

   ... above the field declarations. That way it's initialized before the field initializers call the constructor.

At that point, it should work. It's not necessarily a design I'd use myself, but it at least removes the issues you've got at the moment.

Comment: Do you ever sleep? Okay, your suggestions fixed my issues. "It's not necessarily a design I'd use myself" - why is that? It was just a test and will never get into production, however I wonder what's 'wrong' about it. What happens behind and are there any major drawbacks?

Comment: @xvdiff: I'm not sure what you mean by "What happens behind" but it just doesn't feel very idiomatic to me. I'd usually just use an enum instead - which does mean you need to validate it, but it's the idiomatic way of representing a named set of integer values.